# ee.Image.paint() introduces gaps

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create a mask from a feature collection with one feature:

```
var conus_fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/jesse/aft-app/conus');
var conus = ee.Image().paint(conus_fc);
Map.addLayer(conus_fc);
Map.addLayer(conus);
```

The feature collection looks like this:
[image]

The painted feature collection looks like this:
[image]

I don't know why those gaps are there in the painted image; they are not in the feature collection. I need to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in earth engine. I converted the source shapefile to an image in gdal and uploaded to earth engine and it did not show artifacts.

Comment: The bug should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep, it works !